# Fabric.js - how to resize canvas and keep coordinations like a bigger one

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to have canvas with sizes (changes with click on buttons) 2048x2048 px, 1024x2048px and 2048x1024px.

Everything works like I need, it just behave weird on phones. It's laggy on iphone and android. PC works smooth.

I think its because of resizing of canvas, when I am resizing window, I need canvas to behave like it has maximum resolution. For example if I do 2048x2048 px canvas on mobile which will be ofc resized, I need to catch image coordinations like its 2048x2048px.

Here is my code, I just need to figure out whats wrong and why its not smooth on phones. thanks a lot, I tried literally everything I could.
Using Alpine.js, talwind css and fabric.js

HTML:

```
                let canvas = this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.$refs.canvas, {
                    
                    width: this.canvasSize,
                    height: this.canvasSize,
                  
              
                });
                this.initialCanvasSize = 2048;
                this.scaleCanvasContainer();
                var imageURL = "/images/square.png";
                canvas.setBackgroundColor(
                {source: imageURL, repeat: 'repeat'}, 
                canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                );
                            
                 
                // Image
                window.fabric.Image.fromURL(`https://storage.googleapis.com/storage.web.com/{{$get_photo->image}}`, (img) => {
                    img.set({
                        hasControls: true,
                        hasBorders: true,
                        lockMovementX: false,
                        lockMovementY: false,
                        
                    });
                    img.scaleToHeight(600);
                    img.scaleToWidth(600);
                    canvas.add(img);
                    this.image = img;
                    canvas.add(img).renderAll();
                    
                    canvas.centerObject(img);
                    //this.updateProperties();
                });
                 window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                this.scaleCanvasContainer();
            });
            updateCanvasSize() {
            this.canvasSize = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) * 0.9;
            
        }, 
            updateProperties() {
            let obj = this.image;
            this.scaleX = obj.scaleX;
            this.scaleY = obj.scaleY;
            this.left = obj.left;
            this.top = obj.top;
            this.angle = obj.angle;
             },
             saveChanges() {
            this.updateProperties();             

            let data = {
                scale_x: this.scaleX,
                scale_y: this.scaleY,
                x: this.left,
                y: this.top,
                angle: this.angle
            };
            
            this.SaveEditPhoto(data)
        },
            scaleCanvasContainer() {
            const canvasContainer = this.$refs.canvas.parentElement;
            let scaleFactor;

            const aspectRatio = this.canvas.width / this.canvas.height;

            if (window.innerWidth <= 768) { 
                scaleFactor = Math.min(window.innerWidth / this.initialCanvasSize, 

              window.innerHeight / this.initialCanvasSize);
                } else {
                    scaleFactor = Math.min(window.innerWidth / this.initialCanvasSize / 2, window.innerHeight / this.initialCanvasSize /                              2);
                }

            let newSizeWidth = this.initialCanvasSize * scaleFactor * aspectRatio;
            let newSizeHeight = this.initialCanvasSize * scaleFactor;

            
            canvasContainer.style.width = `${newSizeWidth}px`;
            canvasContainer.style.height = `${newSizeHeight}px`;

            canvasContainer.style.transform = `scale(${scaleFactor})`;
            canvasContainer.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
            },
            resizeCanvas(width, height) {
            this.canvasSize = width;
            this.canvas.setWidth(width);
            this.canvas.setHeight(height);
            this.scaleCanvasContainer();

            if (this.image) {
                const originalCanvasWidth = this.canvas.width;
                const originalCanvasHeight = this.canvas.height;

               
                const newImageScaleX = (width / originalCanvasWidth) * this.image.scaleX;
                const newImageScaleY = (height / originalCanvasHeight) * this.image.scaleY;

             
                this.image.set({
                    scaleX: newImageScaleX,
                    scaleY: newImageScaleY,
                });
                this.canvas.centerObject(this.image);

               
                this.updateProperties();
                this.canvas.renderAll();
            }
        },
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.